# Copying List to Map in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I need to know how to copy from a `list` to a `map` in C++. A code sample would be great.

Comment: What kind of data do you have inside your list?

Comment: do you mean std::vector and std::map?

Comment: These two data structures are used for two different purposes. You need to tell us your transfer function.

Comment: std::list is value list and std::map maps keys to values. what data you want to use as a key for map?

Answer (score 3):

An [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is an associative container, holding key-value pairs. An [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) only holds values. Hence, the question makes no sense unless the list contains the right type of key-value pairs.

*If* your list happened to contain `std::pairs` matching the value type of the target map, you could initialize the map using the iterator constructor:

```
std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>> = ....;
std::map<std::string, int> m(l.begin(), l.end());
```

or you can use the `std::copy` algorithm, as has been suggested elsewhere:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m1;
std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::inserter(m1, m1.begin()));
```

but note here that the "copy" may not be doing what you expect, since the map cannot hold values with the same key.

Comment: How is this an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @Nick: Q: "how to copy", A: "no way, semantically"

Comment: @Vlad: "Yes way", if the list holds pairs. As such, the question *could* make sense, if more context was given.

Comment: @Xeo: the OP didn't seem to reference that the list is of quite special format. In any case, your observation is valid.

Comment: @xeo absolutely right. I just doubted OP would have a list with the right type of pairs. But I should have qualified my answer.

Comment: @Nick I was guessing OP wouldn't have the right type of list, in which case what they are attempting would be impossible. I provided references to that effect. I have since qualified my answer.

Comment: @xeo actually, the fact that the map cannot hold duplicate keys means that you can only perform a real copy under special conditions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the constructor:

```
std::list<std::pair<int, std::string>> thelist = /* ... */ ;
std::map<int, std::string> themap(thelist.begin(), thelist.end());
```

Your list needs to contain suitable key-value pairs for the map.

Comment: +1, this is the only way that list->map can possibly make sense, at least without further context in the question.

Comment: From the context of the question, I would personally doubt the list really contains kvp's.

Comment: @awoodland depending on the definition of "to make sense". A list may contain duplicates, the map cannot contain duplicate keys, so "copying" has to be taken with caution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use [`copy`](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi/0650/bks/SGI_Developer/books/STL_PG/sgi_html/copy.html) for a source `list` and a destination `map`, as `copy` is not directly compatible for a `list` and `map`.

Comment: And what would you copy? Key, Value, KVP?

Comment: Are you sure that this will work?

Comment: the question  edited after i wrote my answer..

Comment: You can use `std::copy`, but only if the list holds the right kind of `std::pairs`.

Answer (score 0):

The list class is, as the name suggests, a list of objects.  A map however is a list of pairs.  So if you have a list of fruits "apple", "pear", "watermelon", you could put them into a map, but would have to map them to something (hopefully something meaningful).

Ex:

```
map<string, string> mapFruits;
mapFruits["apple"] = "red";
mapFruits["pear"] = "yellow";
mapFruits["watermelon"] = "green";
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty examples online of how to output values from a list and plenty of how to add values to a map. So I won't repeat it here. Look at cplusplus.com (although it's  not everyones cup of tea.)

**A warning**: A map will only store uniquely keyed values so you may find there is not a 1:1 mapping between your map items and your list items (i.e you will get the same or less in your map) so be clear first on why you are using each container.